# Flutter IOS back swipe onWillPop not working

Tags: flutter, dart

I wrapped my Scaffold in `WillPopScope`, but my `onWillPop` doesn't work on swipe back on ios, it only works on pressing leading, how to make `onWillPop` work on swipe back?

```
return WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: () async {
          print('pop');
          Navigator.pop(context, product);
          setState(() {
            product.is_favorite = isFavorite;
          });
          return true;
        },
        child: Scaffold(
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer was to create your own custom widgets `CustomPageRoute` and `CustomWillPopScope` and use them.

```
// or we can use just CupertinoPageRoute, it will works too.

class CustomPageRoute extends CupertinoPageRoute {
  @override
  @protected
  bool get hasScopedWillPopCallback {
    return false;
  }
  CustomPageRoute({
    required WidgetBuilder builder,
    RouteSettings? settings,
    bool maintainState = true,
    bool fullscreenDialog = false,
  }) : super(
    builder: builder,
    settings: settings,
    maintainState: maintainState,
    fullscreenDialog: fullscreenDialog,
  );
}
/////////////////////
class CustomWillPopScope extends StatelessWidget {
  const CustomWillPopScope(
      {required this.child,
      this.onWillPop = false,
      Key? key,
      required this.action})
      : super(key: key);

  final Widget child;
  final bool onWillPop;
  final VoidCallback action;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Platform.isIOS
        ? GestureDetector(
            onPanEnd: (details) {
              if (details.velocity.pixelsPerSecond.dx < 0 ||
                  details.velocity.pixelsPerSecond.dx > 0) {
                if (onWillPop) {
                  action();
                }
              }
            },
            child: WillPopScope(
              onWillPop: () async {
                return false;
              },
              child: child,
            ))
        : WillPopScope(
            child: child,
            onWillPop: () async {
              action();
              return onWillPop;
            });
  }
}
```

When we navigate to a page, during Navigator.push we use our CustomPageRoute like this:

```
 Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      CustomPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => ProductScreen()));
```

then
on the page where we need `WillPopScope` we also use our custom `WillPopScope` and in `Navigator.pop()` we pass our data along to the context.

```
return
        CustomWillPopScope(
        action: () {
          print('pop');
          Navigator.pop(context, product);
          setState(() {
            product.is_favorite = isFavorite;
          });
        },
          onWillPop: true,
        child:
        Scaffold(
```

After we have done all these steps `WillPopScope` will work.

Comment: did this is the answer of issue which you have faced

Comment: yes, this is right answer

Comment: ok, glad you have solved your problem. did you do some work on the firebase, post request I also have one problem.

Comment: what problem do you have?

Comment: Future<void> addProduct(Product product) async {
    try {
  const url = "https://flutter-update-74138-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app/Products.json";
  final response = await http.post(
    url as Uri,
    body: json.encode({
      'title ': product.title,
      'description': product.description,
      'imageUrl': product.imageUrl,
      'price': product.price,
      'isFavorite': product.isFavorite
    }),
  );

Comment: above is the code which didn't save data into the firebase

Comment: if you copy this code and put it into the ide then you will understand easly

Comment: I'll take a look and see how it can be solved, give me time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252397/discussion-between-m-shahzad-and-st4tic).

Comment: it does not create swipe back equal to native swipe back, instead it's a custom solution tha barely simulates the real ux